# Swift "file not found" when trying to read text file

Tags: swift

I've been stuck for a couple hours now on this problem. I'm trying to read in a text file and print each line, but I keep getting this error:

`Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “coordinates.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."`

I don't get why this is happening because the txt file is right next to the swift file in the same directory.

Heres the swift code:

```
let filename = "coordinates.txt"
let contents = try! String(contentsOfFile: filename) // where error is occuring

let lines = contents.split(separator:"\n")

for line in lines {
     print("\(line)")
}
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I'm working on this in Xcode IOS

Comment: You're using a relative path, so you're going to get weird behavior. I think relative paths like this are resolved relative to the current working directory (`CWD` env var) of the process, which is probably not something you set yourself. You should use an absolute path, or a path that's relative to some known folder (e.g. the user's home folder, downloads folder, etc.)

Comment: What sort of project is this? iOS? MacOS? if MacOS, is it an app or a command-line tool? Or is this just a "loose" swift file that you are running from the Terminal?

Comment: The project is in XCode IOS

Comment: And `filename = "./coordinates.txt"` didn't work? If not, you could just do `pwd` in terminal in your current directory, then copy and paste that with filename appended to the end for the `filename` constant.

Comment: You need to get the file from the app bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First check wether you have added target on your text file (coordinates.txt)**

Make sure that your text file(coordinates.txt) added target membership.

**Second**

```
let filename = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "coordinates", ofType: "txt")
let contents = try! String(contentsOfFile: filename)
let lines = contents.split(separator:"\n")

for line in lines {
 print("\(line)")
}
```