# "ForEach" code in not running in my Xcode, it shows App quit unexpectedly whenever I use ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CoverImageView: View {
    //MARK: PROPERTIES
    
    //MARK: BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in // after writing this it quits unexpectedly 
                Image("cover-lion")
                    .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            } //LOOP
        } //:TAB
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
```

Comment: Hi Aryan, I'm not sure if we have enough code. If I reproduce your code in a clean Xcode Project it runs.

Comment: Did you tried .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I ran your code with another image, and it worked fine in Xcode 13.2.1 iOS 15.2. Most likely the problem has to do with your image. Have you tried a different one?

Comment: What is `cover-lion`? Where is it stored? Is it in the same directory as your source file? I guess that is not in your system `PATH`, and you aren't otherwise telling the compiled executable what an unqualified path of `cover-lion` means. So how could it ever find it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66395754/swift-file-not-found-when-trying-to-read-text-file has some pointers.

Also, "it shows App quit unexpectedly" - and nothing else? or does it log an error in the terminal, which you could paste here?

Answer (score 0):

You need an array from where you are going to get the data.

**Simple ForEach Without Index**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var items = ["Tanvir", "Ifa", "Shuvo"]
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Simple ForEach with index**

```
VStack{
    ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
        Text(items[index])
    }
 }
```

**EDIT: For Your case. This will load the same image five times:**

I think you do not have the image in Assets folder of your app. Drag the image in the Assets.

```
VStack{
    ForEach(0..<5) { _ in       // _ means no parameter name
        Image("yourImageName")  // put the image in the Assets
    }
}
```

Comment: That changes the meaning of the code. It looks like they just wanted to add the same image 5 times. The problem is likely that the executable's environment couldn't find the file. The solution is to tell it where to get the file, not to change the meaning of the code altogether!

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: I think you do not have the image in Assets folder of your app. Drag the image in the Assets.

Comment: For me your code is running. But sometimes show the message.